# eigenvectors & values to plot 2d stress vector field

Tags: matlab, gnuplot, data-visualization, eigenvector, paraview

I intended to plot a 2d stress field. What I have in hand are 2 eigenvectors and the respective 2 eigenvalues of 2D stress tensor field for all the particles in system. I am afraid that I could not figure out how to evaluate these eigenvectors (direction) and eigenvalues (maximum & minimum stress values) to plot a 2D stress field using any of MATLAB, gnuplot, Grapher, ParaView or any other suitable plate form.

Any form of code (C, C++, MATLAB or ParaView) along with a brief explanation of utilizing this trivial eigen problem will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Matlab quiver](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/quiver.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Akin to matlab's quiver is gnuplot's `with vectors` plotting style.

Out of curiosity, with only the eigenvector and eigenvalues, how do you expect to get the full 2d stress field?  That doesn't seem possible to me  (although my linear algebra is a little rusty) ...